# ZF2 Doctrine create entity whitout primary key

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, zend-framework2

I have a Oracle view table.
I want to create a class Entity of this View, but I get this error:

```
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "PortalAtendimento\Entity\VWAtendimentoContexto". 
Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

How can I can create a Entity without a primary key?

Comment: Read the docs, in particular the identifier generation strategies -> http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line, you can't. You can create an object (view/table) with an identifier that you won't use but Doctrine will require one to be present

```
Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```